# Suitable and efficient data structure for multilevel data

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, hashtable, large-data

In my requirement I have a list of 50 countries in which each country have a list of factories and each factory will have a list of products produced and each product have a list of date of manufacture and each date of manufacture have a large data in it. What is the suitable and efficient data structure for implementing this. Also fast searching and updating of data is very essential. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a database. If you want a specific data structure recommendation, you'll need to specify exactly what your search and update queries will look like, and their respective frequency (but an appropriate answer will still probably be "just use a database, or simulate what one would do").

Comment: And you'll also need to tell us how many factories and products and manufacture dates you have for each respective country, factory and product. And also what "each date of manufacture have a large data in it" means.

Comment: Number of factories differs based on country, but you can safely assume it will not cross 20. Products produced range from 50 to maximum 100. Manufacturing date should be stored till its expiry date and on each day of production the current date is added. Each manufacturing date will have data related to that day, mostly text. CRUD should be done for data in each manufacturing date and it will be done using client end application from anywhere. The client end will connect to cloud application where the database is managed. All data operations should be managed in a centralized cloud.

Comment: Am a budding programmer and I don't have vast knowledge on all IT fields. Am learning by doing. The above requirement is for a challenge I participated. Please guide me for the best way to achieve it, and I will work towards it. Thanks Dukeling for commenting